# .NET unit tests - Assert.IsTrue message?

Tags: .net, vb.net, unit-testing

I'd like to add a message to be displayed in Visual Studio 2010 test results.

I can post a message out if the test fails, but not true.  Is there anyway to do this?

For example:

```
dim quoteNumber as string = Sales.CreateQuote(foo)

assert.IsTrue(quoteNumber <> "")
'I would like to make this something like this: 
assert.isTrue(quoteNumber <> "", falsepart, "Quote number " & quoteNumber & " created")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what unit test framework you're using, but with the Visual Studio unit tests, you can do the following:

```
Assert.IsTrue(quoteNumber <> "", "Quote number must be non-empty")
'I would like to make this something like this: 
Console.WriteLine("Quote number " & quoteNumber & " created")
```

Comment: I'm using the standard visual studio test framework.  
Where does console.writeline go to?  I can't find the right window.

Comment: It will show up in your test results. Right-click a test in the "Test Results" window and choose "View Test Result Details", and it will show up. You can also view it as a column in the Test Results window.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to use Console.WriteLine().  NUnit captures anything written to the console to another tab in the GUI.  I would assume that VisualStudio's test runner would do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `Assert.IsFalse`. Maybe

```
Assert.IsFalse(quoteNumber = "", "Quote number " & quoteNumber & " created")
```